# How get endpoint, which receive message, in async boost::asio handler?

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I assume that computer has several network interfaces. I send async broadcast message over all of them. On some I will receive responses. I need local IP address which receive response.

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, open a distinct socket per local IP. The sockets on which you receive responses will identify the local IP. To list the available network interfaces on a system (in a portable way) you case see http://pocoproject.org. If you do not have portability requirements, the task of listing the local interfaces for your host system may be easier, as it will probably not require a 3'rd party library.